# I need help on not seeing the outside of my background scene in object

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I am creating an ocean underwater scene. I've created a plane and extending the plane and subdivide it but when I use my camera to go underwater, when I go in *Wireframe*, *Solid* and even *Cycles* mode I can see the outside of the extend object.

How can I close this hole?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this is a clipping distance issue. Blender can't render an infinite distance, so the viewport have a minimum and maximum render distance.

In the Viewport > Sidebar > View tab > View panel:

[image]

For the camera, select it, then go to the Properties Editor > Camera tab > Lens panel:

[image]

You can easily add one zero to the Camera's End clipping setting, the viewport does the same.

Do not put crazy values, just put what you need, and always increase/decrease both start and end. If the two values are too far apart, you will have weird rendering issues.

Comment: I’ve been able to fix the issue for the distance, Does the viewport and the Camera’s End clipping settings have to be the values?